# Instance of closure when i'm looking for an instance of entity in form symfony

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

In a Symfony form, I have to add an instance of an Entity but I don't want to add all of the tuples of this entity in my form's choice. When I use `ChoiceType::class` I get this error:

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Authorization or null",
> "instance of Closure" given at property path "authorization".

This is my form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $options=[];
        $builder
            ->add('authorization', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Intervenant' => function(?AuthorizationRepository $authoRepo){
                        $result = $authoRepo->findOneBy(['name'=>'intervenant']);
                        return $result;
                    },
                    'Administrateur Structure' => function(?AuthorizationRepository $authoRepo) {
                        $result = $authoRepo->findOneBy(['name' => 'admin Structure']);
                        return $result;
                    }
                ],
                'label' => 'Choisir le type de demande',
                ])

            ->add('structure', EntityType::class, ['class'=>Structure::class,
                'choice_label'=>'completeName'
                ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ValidationAuthorization::class,
        ]);
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
public function authorization(Request $request, Users $user): Response
    {
        $valid = new ValidationAuthorization();
        $formAutho = $this->createForm(AuthorizationType::class, $valid);
        $formAutho->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formAutho->isSubmitted() && $formAutho->isValid()) {
            $valid->setIsValide(false);
            $valid->setUser($user);
            $this->entityManager->persist($valid);
            $this->entityManager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Votre demande a été prise en compte');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('users_index');
        }
        return $this->render('users/authorization.html.twig', [
            'formAutho' => $formAutho->createView(),
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: what does your ValidationAuthorization::getAuthorization() look like?

Answer (score 0):

It does looks like you should use the `EntityType` instead of `ChoiceType` and just play with the query builder to get a subset of your `Authorization` entities. So something like:

```
$builder
    ->add('authorization', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Authorization::class,
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('va')
                ->where('va.name IN ("intervenant", "admin Structure")')
                ->orderBy('va.name', 'DESC');
        },
        'label' => 'Choisir le type de demande',
    ])
    ->add('structure', EntityType::class, ['class'=>Structure::class,
        'choice_label'=>'completeName'
    ]);
```

Comment: I believe the class should be just `Authorization`, so without the "Validation" ...